# display, in multiple lines, objects in JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing

Thanks for helping me,

```
for(Commande commande : Videotheque.getInstance().getListCommande()){
                listLbl.setText(listLbl.getText() + "\n" + commande.toString()); //problem to display on multiple lines
            }
```

I want to display multiple order (Command object) in multiple lines.
It might be feasible using html with something like that but it doesn't work

```
list.setText("<html>" + listLbl.getText() + "<br>" + commande.toString() + "</html>");
```

when i use this code, it only displays the last order, whereas with the first part i had all the orders on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<html>");
for (Commande commande : Videotheque.getInstance().getListCommande()) {
    sb.append(listLbl.getText()).append("<br>").append(commande.toString());
}
sb.append("</html>");
listLbl.setText(sb.toString());
```